# dplyr mutate apply a custom function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In my data I have three groups, 4 time points (i), and a dependent variable (RTfiltered).

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  i = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                  RTfiltered = c(100,105,94,33,97,87,65,20,19,4,11,56))
```

For each group, I want to to fit a linear regression model RTfiltered~i, and if the slope effect is significantly different from zero, return RTfiltered-slope*i. Otherwise, return RTfiltered. Here's a function that does this:

```
correctOrderEffects <- function(df) {
  fit <- lm(RTfiltered ~ i, data=df)
  if (summary(fit)$coefficients[2,4]>0.05) {
    return(df$RTfiltered)
  } else {
    slope = fit$coefficients[2];
    return(df$RTfiltered-slope*(df$i-2.5))
  }
}
```

I want to create a new column in my df that will hold the output of correctOrderEffects for each group. What is the best way to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `group_by()` on 'group' and then apply your function to the subgroups with `do()`. This replicates the 'RTfiltered' you provided in the example, is this what you are looking for?

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(mutate(., effects = correctOrderEffects(.)))
```